# Android Textview with MaxLenght and maxLines with the same maxLenght

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to configure a TextView which has maxLines=3 and EACH LINE of it has maxLenght=30.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use maxWidth function for actual 30 chars (avg. 1 char width x 30). So each line length will be max 30 chars.
2. You can use 3 textView instead of 1 textView. And you can control from code after entering every char. `textView.getText().length() <= 30`